# Can't get image to 100% width (not due to small container, not background)

Tags: html, image, css, width

I have got this image that I want to display on my front page.
It is on top of my background image (which has a working 100% span)
But the image on top of it has a little border of +- 5px showing the background. The border needs to go :)

My CSS looks like this: (with the navigation that is fixed to top)

```
body {
    background: url(backgr_1.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center bottom;
    background-size:cover;
}

nav {
    position:fixed;
    z-index: 100;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    width: 100%;
    height: 58px;
    font-family: 'chineserocks';
    font-size: 3em;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top: 0;
    }

li {
    display: inline-block;
}

a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left: 4em;   
    }

#backroots_head {
    width: 100%;
}

#head_section {
    width: 100%;
}
```

and my HTML like this:

```
<body>
    <section id="head_section">
        <img id="backroots_head" src="backroots_head.jpg">
    </section>
```

and all the rest of the html etc.

So that is basic stuff.

What i have tried:
 - Adding a max width of 3000px
 - margin 0, padding 0
 - width 105% (yes i'm desperate xD)
 - position fixed (worked, but then you can't scroll to the content that is under the picture.
 - adding a width 100% div around it

There is no container around the image or section with a set width, so that isnt the problem too.
Im really stuck on this one. Any solution is welcome.
Kind regards

Comment: How big is the physical image?

Comment: `margin:0` where? are you using a reset? ... can be the body margin?

Comment: I guess you need to reset body, div, section ... with margin, padding 0... Do you have a link to the site? Or a fiddle?

Comment: Is there any CSS targeting the "head-section" element?

Comment: Can you produce a JSFiddle for this? It will be easier if we didn't have to picture it in our heads what you are looking at. It sounds like a border:none; it also sounds like an overflow, it also sounds like a margin and/or position relative, etc... it could be so many things.

Comment: The fact that position: fixed worked suggests that a parent element has the padding/margin that u talk about. Try adding * {margin: 0; padding: 0} as a test.

Comment: please provide the url??? or jsfiddle

Comment: Did you try vertical-align:top;?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I set the body margin to 0 to get rid of the spaces around the image. It scales 100% for me.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
body { margin: 0px; }
#backroots_head { width: 100%; }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<section id="head_section"><img id="backroots_head" src="backroots_head.jpg"></section>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The image I used is 1000x1000. My browser is 1980x1080 and the image stretches 100%, no matter what size I set the browser to.

Comment: yesssss the body margin/padding was the solution. Thanks a lot!